clickhouse json field's default value
I have a table tb(b Object(json)) in clickhouse v23. SET allow_experimental_object_type = 1
CREATE TABLE tb(b JSON, acquisition_at timestamp) ENGINE = MergeTree() PARTITION BY toYYYYMM(acquisition_at) order by acquisition_at;

and I will insert dynamic JSON into tb.
insert into tb (b, acquisition_at) values('{"a": 0}', '2024-07-25 09:00:00'), ('{"d": 1}', '2024-07-25 09:00:01'), ('{"c": 2}', '2024-07-25 09:00:01')

so I query:
select b.c from tb

I got:
┌─b.c─┐
│   0 │
│   0 │
│   2 │
└─────┘

the first row and second row which key d does not exist, but clickhouse still returns the 0 for me, how can I filter these rows?
I want to return the records that the key d truly exists
| b.c |
| ----|
| 1   |


hi - please include your table schema and INSERT example. In my testing I get just payload.d = 1. I would note also that Object(JSON) is experimental also and will be soon be deprecated, as it has many problems. I will soon be replaced by the Dynamic() data type: https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/data-types/dynamic - for now, we would generally recommend using the GA JSON* functions: https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/functions/json-functions

hi - is there any ways to migrate the Object(json) data type to dynamic data type?
